# Jq getting output from nested hash

Tags: jq

Hi I am trying to parse below hash with jq

```json
{
    "name": "a",
    "data": [
    {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "mykeypair"
    },
    {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "int",
        "value": 123
    }
    ]
}
```

and get output like

```
a,string,mykeypair
a,int,123
```

I am able to get output like this

```
a,string,mykeypair
a,int,mykeypair
a,string,123
a,int,123
```

Comment: where does `b` come from? Elaborate your condition

Comment: my bad, its ''a"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.name as $n | .data[] | [$n, .type, .value] | @csv' file.json
```

The output:

```
"a","string","mykeypair"
"a","int",123
```

---

If it's mandatory to output unquoted values:

```
jq -r '.name as $n | .data[] | [$n, .type, "\(.value)"] | join(",")' file.json
```

The output:

```
a,string,mykeypair
a,int,123
```